# Access and restrict organization pages in client network

Tags: .net, sonarqube, vpn

0

Im working on a sonarqube project for .net code which needs to be built to run the scan. However due to dependency issues, I'm planning to have the sonarqube set up (which runs on my organization VPN) in client's network. How can I achieve it without providing access to other projects. In short, I should be able to run my organization's sonar qube for scan in client's network by providing access to client's project alone restricting other projects' data.